# TypeError: (0,o.useState) is not a function. (In '(0,o.useState)(null)', '(0,o.useState)' is undefined)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

This is a very basic React native app, with login, and navigation. And as soon as user logs in, and gets navigated to the new screen, I get this error, have no idea what is the cause of the issue or which component it could be. Can someone help. Thanks!

Here are the logcat logs.

```
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS: This error is located at:
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in E
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in ForwardRef
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in k
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in ForwardRef
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in PanGestureHandler
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in k
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in ForwardRef
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in R
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in A
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in h
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in T
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in k
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in B
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in V
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in f
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in w
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in I
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in ForwardRef
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in k
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in ForwardRef
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in PanGestureHandler
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in k
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in ForwardRef
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in R
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in A
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in h
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in T
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in ForwardRef
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in k
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in ForwardRef
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in PanGestureHandler
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in k
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in ForwardRef
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in R
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in A
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in h
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RNCSafeAreaProvider
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in GestureHandlerRootView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in T
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in ForwardRef
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in ForwardRef
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in k
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Provider
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Provider
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Provider
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Provider
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Provider
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Provider
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in Unknown
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in RCTView
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in View
12-22 17:04:59.937 11560 11625 E ReactNativeJS:     in C
```

Although it looks like the useState variable isn't defined, or the main component's screen is getting swapped, but I'm unable to pin point the issue.

Most importantly, this happens when I build the apk, and manually install it on my android physical phone. And **doesn't** happen when I'm running the app via USB debugging.

Comment: Please post relevant code, which will more than likely be the component which mounts directly after the user logs in

Comment: Did you solve this Shubham? We´re getting this error as well. And it's near impossible to debug due to the minification. Development build works fine, is only when building a productions build where it fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had the same issue, and managed to fix it by searching for the exact minified function in the minified code (in this case `(0,o.useState`), then search around that code to find some string or identifier that wasn't minifed (found a prop name that was a string) that we could use to find the place in the source code.

There we saw that VS Code had auto imported useState from the wrong place (`import { useEffect } from 'react/cjs/react.development'` ). So we just removed that and imported useState from "react" instead.

(Also had to clear all react native cache to make this work)

Comment: I had this same problem. thankfully I was able to track it down.  does anyone know a way of configuring vs code not to do this?   I'm *not* using the Auto-Import extension, so I'm a bit puzzled.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem,

I've realized that my Expo SDK version was an older one, I've upgraded Expo SDK and re-deployed my app, problem did not occur again.